# JPanel updates incorrectly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have an Agenda application that contains two JFrames it uses. One displays the overall calendar while another launches when a day is chosen and allows for you to edit the events on that day. The problem is when I remove events it updates very randomly as multiple events are removed.

Here is an example execution:

- Added 5 events to 1 day ev, ev2, ev3, ev4, ev5 | Displays the 5 events.
- Then remove ev3 | Updates to only display event 1.
- Remove ev 3 (was event 4) | Displays events in the order of ev, ev2, ev5, ev4.
- Remove event 2 | Displays events in the order of ev, ev5, ev3, ev4.
- Remove event 1 | Displays events in the order of ev, ev2, ev3, ev4.

The only remaining event (ev5) still exists in the array of events and is updated to the main frame so I know that the functionality of it is working. I am assuming I am not adding them correctly or updating the JPanel correctly. Any information helps as I am pretty new to this but here is an example of the remove buttons actionPerformed where it updates the panels.

```
if(e.getSource() == remove) {

    // Update main GUI

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What event number are you removing?");
    if(input == null) {
        return;
    }
    int response = -1;
    while (response == -1) {
        try {
            response = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Event number couldn't be read. Input numerical value.");
        }
    }
    response -= 1;
    try {
        current.removeEventFromDay(dayNumberInMonth, response);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This event didn't exist.");
        return;
    }
    BorderLayout layout = (BorderLayout) panel.getLayout();
    panel.remove(layout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER));
    JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 1, 10, 5));
    String[] events = current.getDayEvents(dayNumberInMonth);
    for(int i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        center.add(new JButton((i + 1 + ": ") + events[i]));
    }
    panel.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.repaint();
    // Update other GUI
    JFrame otherFrame = calendar.getFrame();
    JPanel otherPanel = calendar.getPanel();
    int leadingDays = calendar.getLeadingDays();
    BorderLayout otherLayout = (BorderLayout) otherPanel.getLayout();
    otherPanel.remove(otherLayout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER));
    JPanel otherCenter = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 7, 5, 5));
    for(int i = 0; i < leadingDays; i++) {
        otherCenter.add(new JButton());
    } 
    JButton[] dayBtns = new JButton[current.getMonthListLength()];
    for(int i = 0; i < current.getMonthListLength(); i++ ) {
        events = current.getDayEvents(i);
        String list = "";
        if(events.length > 1) {
            list = events[0] + "...";
        }
        if (events.length == 1) {
            list = events[0];
        }
        dayBtns[i] = new JButton();
        dayBtns[i].setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("" + (1 + i));
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(list);
        dayBtns[i].add(label1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        dayBtns[i].add(label2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        dayBtns[i].addActionListener(calendar);
        otherCenter.add(dayBtns[i]);
    }
    otherPanel.add(otherCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    otherFrame.add(otherPanel);
    otherFrame.revalidate();
    otherFrame.repaint();
}
```

Edit:
Here is the removeEventFromDay method but it doesn't contain the functionality but rather it makes sure the correct day object is being used. So here is the removeEvent method from the day class along with it.

```
public void removeEventFromDay(int day, int event) {
    this.monthDays[day].removeEvent(event);
}
```

Please note that this method is located within the day class and the previous is in the year class.

```
public void removeEvent(int eventNumber) {

    if(events.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There are no events to remove");
    }
    if(eventNumber >= events.length || eventNumber < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This event doesn't exist");
    }

    events[eventNumber] = null;
    String list = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        if(events[i] != null) {
            list += events[i] + " | ";
        }
    }

    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(list);

    String[] temp = new String[events.length - 1];

    String sum = "";

    int i = 0;
    while(lineScanner.hasNext()) {

        String add = lineScanner.next();

        if(!add.equals("|")) {
            sum += add;
            if(lineScanner.hasNext()) {
                sum += " ";
            }
        } else {
            sum.trim();
            temp[i] = sum;
            i++;
            sum = "";
        }
    }

    events = new String[temp.length];

    for(int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
        events[j] = temp[j];
    }
}
```

2nd Edit:

I ended up making it just create a new frame object when it removed the event and closed the other. It fixed the issue and caused it to update correctly but I never could figure out for the random appearances of past lists buttons.

Comment: I don't see the method the actionListener methods of calendar here.

Comment: It creates a GUI that is connected to a day for whatever day of the year is chosen.

Comment: Yes, but aren't you asking for suggestions on how to fix a problem with this?

Comment: Here is a pastebin of it https://pastebin.com/jCSXdxCA

Comment: It sounds like your problem is in the `removeEventFromDay` method.  Please edit your question and add the code for that method.

Comment: 1) *"application that contains two JFrames"* That's one too many. See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).